# text and images in same line

Tags: jquery, image, menu

I'm having trouble to fix the basic code, i thought maybe you can help me ...
please take look at the sample code at

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/Alidad/kkaYc/>
```

As you can see that when you select images from menu and it will show image on yellow background, and then you can put title name on the text field, it wills how title name on top of images.

however, I'm trying to figure out how to fix to show all in SAME LINE not first line title and second line images, but to show title name first and images in same line together!

I tried to move around  it doesn't working right.

Any idea!

AM

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` instead of `div`:

```
<span id="Displaytitle"></span>
<span id="image"></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kkaYc/1/